# Lag sending sensor data via UDP - how to slow down sensor updates?

Tags: java, android, performance, sockets

**MY ISSUE**

I'm working on an app that sends sensor data over UDP. The data sent is correct, but it runs into heavy lag at times. It appears that there are simply too many packets being sent. The stream gets held up, causing a slow-down of received packets followed by a burst of many packets at once.

I feel that the issue is how fast the sensor is being updated. onSensorChanged is being called as often as the sensor updates, which then triggers the call to the udpClient asynctask. **Is there a way that I can slow this down?** The sensor updates very quickly and therefore sends packets very frequently.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I have tried adjusting the update rate with SENSOR_DELAY_ constants as well as microsecond int values, but this has no effect. The android developer page states that this is only a hint, and not a guarantee of the sensor update rate. I also tried making onSensorChanged() and doInBackground() methods as minimal as possible with little to no results.

If any suggestions could be provided as to how I could slow down the sensor updates/UDP send rate, it would be greatly appreciated

I'm running a simple Python server on my laptop to receive the strings sent from the android app, in case it's of any use. I'm listening to Accel, Gyro and Lux, but only outputting Accel in X direction for now.

// code omitted

Comment: Could you just ignore sensorupdates e.g. if System.nanotime has changed by less than a threshold value?